# Derived geometry and theoretical physics

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry

Is there any link between derived geometry and theoretical physics?
for example with particle physics or quantum mechanics?

Specifically something that included the obstruction bundle.

If possible I would like to have some bibliographic references.

Comment: A search  "find title derived geometry" at https://inspirehep.net gives half a dozen papers that might be relevant to your question.

Comment: There's an extensive literature by mathematical physicists effectively about derived geometry, usually under names such as $Q$-manifolds or dg manifolds.

Comment: Plenty to see at the nLab on this, such as https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/BV-BRST+formalism

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers.